# Multi match doesnt work with constant score

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to disable TF/IDF using constant_score for a multi_match query.

```
GET cities/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "new york",
                "fields": [
                 "city",
                 "village"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but i got the following error:

```
 "reason": "[constant_score] query does not support [query]".
```

I also tried without using the query wrapper

```
GET cities/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "constant_score": {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "new york",
                    "fields": [
                     "city",
                     "village"
                    ]
                  }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

But i got the following error :

```
"[constant_score] query does not support [multi_match]".
```

Is there a workaround to use them together?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in elasticsearch, but reading [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/compound-queries.html)

> `constant_score` query
>
> A query which wraps another query, but executes
>   it in filter context. All matching documents are given the same
>   “constant” _score.

I believe you need something like this:

```
GET cities/_search
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "new york",
          "fields": [
            "city",
            "village"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, is as says @Hooman . Also if you checked the documentation from [ignoring TF/IDF](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ignoring-tfidf.html) seems that query syntax is incorrect ...